# problem with transformation to_timestamp python sql on databricks

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to implement a transformation in python sql on databricks, I have tried several ways but without success, I request a validation please:

```
%sql
 SELECT aa.AccountID__c as AccountID__c_2,
  aa.LastModifiedDate,
  to_timestamp(aa.LastModifiedDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") as test
  FROM EVENTS aa
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

It can be seen that the validation is not correct, but even so it is executed on the engine and returns null.

I have also tried performing a substring on the LastModifiedDate field from 1 to 19, but without success ...

Answer (score 0):

The date format you provided does not agree with the date format of that column, so you got null. Having said that, for standard date formats like the format you have, there is no need to provide any date format at all. Simply using `to_timestamp` will give the correct results.

```sql
%sql
SELECT aa.AccountID__c as AccountID__c_2,
  aa.LastModifiedDate,
  to_timestamp(aa.LastModifiedDate) as test
FROM EVENTS aa
```